# jQuery - Click a link to choose a select menu option

Tags: jquery, select, select-menu

I have a select menu in my form that I want to hide and replace with an unordered list.  I've figured out how to copy the select options to links within list items, but I can't figure out how to make the links choose the corresponding select option when clicked.  Can someone give me some clarity?

Here's my code so far:

```
var states = $("#state option").map(function(){ 
                  return '<li><a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>';
             }).get().join("");

$("#states-modal ul").append(states);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#states-modal").delegate("a", "click", function() {
  $("#state").val( $(this).text() );
});

$("#state option").each(function(){ 
  $("<li>")
  .append("<a>", {href: "#", text: $(this).text()})
  .appendTo("#states-modal ul");
});
```

Comment: This worked!  It took me a minute to figure out that the value must be the same as the text itself.  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
$("#states-modal").find("a").click(function() {
    $("#state").val($(this).text());
});
```